# Powershell command not found after PSSession Import

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to add external contact to MS Exchange with Powershell.

```
$username = "username@domain.com"
$password = "password"
$secure_password = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credencial = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $secure_password)    
$session_name = "office365_session"

foreach($tmp in Get-PSSession){
    if ($tmp.Name -eq $session_name) {
        $opened_session = Get-PSSession -Name $session_name
    }
}

if ($opened_session -eq $null) {
    $opened_session = New-PSSession -Name $session_name -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/" -Credential $credencial -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction Stop
    Import-PSSession $opened_session -AllowClobber -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction Stop -DisableNameChecking | Out-Null
}

New-MailContact -Name "test" -DisplayName "test user" -ExternalEmailAddress "some.email@mail.com" -FirstName "Test" -LastName "User"
```

But "New-MailContact" command is not found and throws an error:

```
New-MailContact : The term 'New-MailContact' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

How to run that "New-MailContact" command? Maybe I need import something else or maybe there is another way to add contact?

Comment: Add the snap-in after you import the session.

Answer (score 0):

You missed out the crucial part which is creating a session to the Exchange box therefore your import doesn't work.

Here is an example for O365

```
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell -Credential $credencial  -Authentication Basic –AllowRedirection;
```

only then you can run

```
Import-PSSession $session -AllowClobber -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction Stop -DisableNameChecking | Out-Null

New-MailContact -Name "test" -DisplayName "test user" -ExternalEmailAddress "some.email@mail.com" -FirstName "Test" -LastName "User"
```

Comment: I have not missed creating session before "New-MailContact" command, only copied a wrong script. Sorry :)
I have updated my powershell script in question.

Comment: Change your import to `Import-PSSession $session -AllowClobber -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction Stop` and you will get meaningful output. The new module will be downloaded as file(something temp, ie _tmp_yywgcdto.ni0_). Then run `Get-Command -Module _yourModuleName_` ie `Get-Command -Module  tmp_yywgcdto.ni0`. You should get a bunch of exchange commands or an error

Comment: I used  
    `$import = Import-PSSession $session -AllowClobber -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction Stop`
    `Get-Command -Module $import.Name`  
I got a bunch of commands, but New-MailContact command doesn't exist in a list.

Comment: Are there any Exchange commands? Anything out of `Get-Command -Module  $import.Name -Name *mail*`? You Should get 100+ command like _new-mailbox_ or _get-mailbox_, _get-mailcontact_ etc.

Comment: Yes, I got about 40 commmands with `*mail*` ie `Get-Mailbox`, `Set-Mailbox`, `Set-MailUser`, but any command to add a mail contact.

Comment: Are you able to create contacts using Exchange Admin Center on O365 portal? If not then the account you are using to login does not have the necessary rights. If that's not the case - I am spent :)

Comment: Commands appeared after granting admin rights. Thanks for help :)